# Where can I find the heating unit stabilizers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

[image]

Where can I find the heating unit stablizers for the mission **Citadel: Heating Unit Stablizers**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can acquire the heating unit stablizers via one of two ways.

- First option: Acquire them from the N7: Cerberus Fighter Base mission.
  [image]
- Second option: Purchase them from Spectre terminal on the 2nd floor of the Citadel for ~9000 credits.

Note that the stablizers will only be available from the Spectre terminal if you missed getting them from the first option.

Comment: I found these difficult to find in the base, so I've added a screenshot.